# Создание программы по типу календарика с заметками

Tags: python, calendar, асинхронность

пишу программу для одной компании,суть программы заключается в бронировании столов по времени и дням (грубо говоря как календарь на телефоне с заметками) только преобразован в интерфейсе. Питон знаю,но не знаю с чего начать ,как оформить интерфейс и чтобы все норм работало. Подскажите с чего мне отталкиваться и где искать ?

Comment: если у вас такие вопросы... то VBA + Excel. Я думаю для кафе будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Все же продемонстрирую, о чем же я.

Интерфейс? Есть. Логика? Есть. Можно ли автоматизировать и запоминать задачи? ДА!

Ниже приведена самая легкая программа на свете:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это работает и куда это все пишется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слегка напоминает мощную `IDE`. Считаю очень удобно, с возможностью очень быстро написать годную интерфейс затычку для разных задач.

Comment: Игнорируя хейторов vba: помоему идеальный ответ -- простой инструмент отлично подходящий под задачу из вопроса. Единственно вопрос оффтопик

Comment: хм,довольно интересно... попробовать можно если заказчику подойдет такое оформление ,благодарю за ответ!))